# GLSL abs() broken?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, driver, glsl

I'm making a Gaussian blur shader in GLSL. Since the convolution kernel is symmetrical, I store one half of it. I write:

```
vec3 glow = vec3(0.0);
for (int i = -WIDTH; i <= WIDTH; i++) {
    uint j = abs(i);
    glow += kernel[j] + texelFetch(u_glowTexture, coord + ivec2(i, 0), 0);
}
```

Strangely, this is drawing the blur slightly to the left of what it should be. But then I replace that third line with:

```
uint j = i * sign(i);
```

And now it's working like I expect. Have I broken `abs()`? Have I really found a driver bug?

Comment: What is your `GL_VERSION` and `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION`?

Comment: Does `uint j = uint(abs(i));` work?

Comment: Your suggestion is not working for me. I've got #version 420 at the top of my source file. glxinfo shows "4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.64" and "4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler".

Comment: I made a similar observation. I needed determine the length of a particular vector which worked for every vector I assigned except something like: (0,y) where x is any float value. In this case it returned 0, which is impossible if you remind on how abs() should be implemented. I worked around this by using the normal definition of abs = sqrt(x*x+y*y+...) which worked for me. I assume the GLSL is some kind of a mine field what ever hardware vendor you use. If it where not for the NSight debugger I'd never have found this error/bug whatever.. :/

Comment: You gave me an idea to replace abs function on sign. Thanks. I had the same issue. My shader worked perfect on desktop, but it didn't work on mobile. So I had to use sign.

Answer (score 3):

Abs() start to support integers at 1.30 and doubles at 4.10 version. Might be an unobvious problem with versions and types. try to debug with floats instead of ints. If that does not help than isolate and debug abs() via screen-space shader and  use it output as fragment color.